# Flask - Render dynamic page URL based on inputs provided

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Flask project that has a simple page which gets input from the users and returns back an output. I am trying to see if I can get a dynamic URL for the web page. Given below are my form and route for this web page:

**Form**

```
<form action=""enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="POST">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
<table>
{{ render_field(form.name, size=50) }}
    <tr class="submit">
        <td>
            <button type="submit">Report</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Views**

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users():
    form = UsersForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        output = user(name=form.name.data)

        return send_file(output, attachment_filename = f'UserReport_{name}.csv', as_attachment=True)

    return render_template('name', form=form)
```

The above works just fine.

Page URL is `www.website.com/name`

I however am trying to see if I can have the webpage URL set to change dynamically based on the value entered in the form (`name` field). For example, if name is `person1`, I would like to have the URL set to `www.website.com/name/person1`

Comment: Python Flask has a redirect function, maybe you can use that? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343812/redirecting-to-url-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

Since your route is set to /users, shouldn't it be `www.website.com/users/person1` ?

For dynamic URLs, you could try something like the following

```
@app.route('/users/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users(username):
...
```

To access say /users/person1, you can then use `return redirect` as follows :

```
return redirect(url_for("users",username=form.name.data))
```

Relevant :
[How to generate dynamic urls in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107885/how-to-generate-dynamic-urls-in-flask)

Comment: yes I am trying to have the page redirected to `www.website.com/users/person1`. When I tried 

`@app.route('/users/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def users(username):
...`

I keep getting `GET /users HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: strange, if you passed username correctly, you should be getting /users/something instead. Are you sure that the username variable is being passed correctly to url_for ?