# Creating multiple and dynamic routes for one function in Flask | Python

Tags: python, forms, flask, redirect, dynamic-url

I'm trying to create a verification program where a user goes to a URL and then they get verified.

For each user, I want to create a new url `example.com/verificationUser`, for user 2 it'd be `example.com/verificationUser2`.

How can I set a "dynamic" app route in Flask?

```py
@app_route(dynamic)
def do_this():
   return "hello"
```

I want the same function to run on a new app route. so both `example.com/verificationUser` and `example.com/verificationUser2` get returned `hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you do it

```
@app.route('/verification/<name>')
def profile(name):
    return f'Hello {name}'
```

- Here a cool [Tutorial](https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/generating-dynamic-urls-with-flask).
- [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107885/how-to-generate-dynamic-urls-in-flask).