# Associate methods of an object to API URL routes with Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, lambda, url-routing, api-design

I want to associate a few methods of a (real world) object to Flask URL routes:

```
class Door:
    def __init__(self, location):
        pass
    def open(self):
        pass
    def close(self):
        pass
    def openlater(self, waitseconds=2):
        pass

d = Door(location="kitchen")

app.add_url_rule("/door/open", view_func=lambda: d.open())
app.add_url_rule("/door/close", view_func=lambda: d.close())
app.add_url_rule("/door/openlater", view_func=lambda: d.openlater(waitseconds=10))

# or (if we don't override optional parameters):

for func in ['open', 'close', 'openlater']:
    app.add_url_rule(f"/door/{func}", view_func=lambda: getattr(d, func)())
```

But this does not work:

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function:

**How to do this properly with Python Flask?**

Note:

I could do

```
app.add_url_rule(f"/door/{func}", view_func=getattr(d, func))
```

but then I don't have any `lambda` anymore and I cannot set parameters.

Comment: Django has an `as_view()`...and I'm not familiar with Flask but it looks to have a similar method too...https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.views.View.as_view

Comment: @ViaTech In my example, `Myobj` is not a `View` class with methods get, post, etc. but rather `Myobj` is a real-world model for an object.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107885/how-to-generate-dynamic-urls-in-flask

Answer (score 1):

To create views and map them to a URL, you should create routes. Do this the following way:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Now when you access your webpage you get `Hello World` on screen. The `add_url_rule` is hardly use anymore.

If you want your URL to be dynamic you can do the following:

```
@app.route('/func/<func>')
def index(func):
    return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: I used this solution before, but since I have **many** methods in my object, I would have a lot of duplicated code with your solution.  I'm looking for a way to create 15 routes for most methods of an object with a single loop.

Comment: I edited my code, you can use dynamic url's to overcome this and not have 15 different methods, just and if statement in the route depending on what the user typed

Comment: @OlauPla does whatever is passed in the `<func>` also get passed as an argument in `index(func)`?

Comment: Yes it's the same, If you type example.com/func/example. "Example" will get passed